# About phonological history of Middle French

Tags: phonology, etymology, french, sound-change, history

Schwa in hiatus dwindled in French a few centuries ago. Compare the example "saputum > sëu > su" at
[Wikipedia/History of French](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_French#Internal_phonological_history)

Does anyone know WHEN this sound change occurred? I assume sometime between the 13th and 16th centuries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this thesis, it occurred around the 13th century.

> Deletion of schwa in hiatus with a preceding vowel, as well as the
> emergence of the Modern French elision rule appeared relatively early
> (ca. 13th century) and is explainable by natural criteria such as
> creation of a preferred syllable structure, maximum differentiation
> and preferred stress placement. With respect to schwa in hiatus with a
> preceding vowel, the process of effacement is characterized as a
> variable rule *until around the sixteenth century*.

[Theoretical Implications of Schwa Deletion in French_Master's Thesis_Horne](https://ruor.uottawa.ca/bitstream/10393/22483/1/EC55725.PDF)